# How long does republished app need to wait to appear again on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

For some technical reason, we had to unpublish our app. But after like 5 minutes, we republished it again. But now after 4 days, the app is still unavailable on Google Play, even though the release status is "Available on Google Play".

[image]

The app is having 2 "In review" updates. Is that the reason why it hasn't reappeared in Google Play yet ? I contacted Google by mail but it's weekends now so kinda hard to get the response quickly.

[image]

[image]

UPDATE: I just test another app (which has no update). The app's appeared again after republish about few minutes. So the "In-review" updates are possibly the problem here.

Comment: There's no real estimate. Sometimes it is as low as 40 minutes, and sometimes about 7~8 days. It is possible that app is not visible due to these pending updates.

Comment: The current version status is "Available on Google Play", so I think it's kinda weird

Comment: I am faced the same issue i am updated my app on 21st and it will go live on 26th it took nearly 5 days to go live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so the reason is the in-review update. Even when you have an "Available on Google Play" version, you still have to wait for the "In-review" version to make your app truly published when you republish it with a pending review version. Weird case.

Answer (score 0):

I searched online in some resources & all they said is typically 3 days at max for the app to be visible again,if u didn't get ur app shown till now u can contact the support at : https://support.google.com/googleplay/?hl=en-GB#topic=3364260
Hope i helped you a bit.

Comment: Already contacted. But it's weekends now, so I have to wait like at least a day or two, which has already damaged our marketing plan. And it's kinda weird since the current version status is "Available on Google Play"

Comment: the same issue happened to a game i forgot its name, when u search the game through Google it's there & written "available" but when u enter Play store nothing is there.All Good luck to you pale.

Comment: I use the direct link to check if it's live or not. Search depends on many things. The link only depends on the app is live or not